# Codeigniter Foreign Key data retrieve

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreign-keys

I'm using codeigniter 3.0 and new to it. This is my database structure. How to access person name through single command.

This is my table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

This is Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `work` (`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `personname` int(11) NOT NULL,  `date` varchar(220) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),  FOREIGN KEY (`personname`) REFERENCES person(id))
```

Here is my model for getting data:

```
$query = $this->db->get('work');
    return $query;
```

it only returns person id. But i need name of the person.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
                  ->from('work')
                  ->join('person', 'person.id = work.personname')
                  ->get();

return $query;
```

Use it like this:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
        echo $row->name;
}
```

You can read the docs here on how to use the query builder:

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: what if two tables having same attribute of **name**?

Comment: @snAtchnAren It works just like a regular SQL query. You can do `->select('person.name')`